# How to specify the path when importing service into service and component?

Tags: angular

I know in my service and component I need to use import {MyService} from '../my-service' if I want to import a service.

But my question is:

Is there a quick way to specify the path where my service is? Sometimes I use `'../'`, sometimes I use `'./'`. Sometimes I have to use `'../parentFolderOfMyService'`, sometimes I have to use `'../parentFolderOfMyService/my-service'`.

P.S. I am using visual studio 2017.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

./ refers to the current directory (the directory of the file you are writting)

../ refers to the parent directory

The names are just the names of the directories

To avoid having to write the name of the file you can use [barrels](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/barrel.html)

Comment: If I did not use some tools like barrels, do you know why sometimes I have to use '../parentFolderOfMyService', sometimes I have to use '../parentFolderOfMyService/my-service'

Comment: The second method will always work, the first will only work if you have an index barrel inside "parentFolderOfMyService" or if you have a barrel with the name "parentFolderOfMyService" in ../

Answer (score 0):

It's not about Service or component , all about folder/files hierarchy.

when we will use `../../something1/something2/service` is when our would be like this.
importing service.ts in our service.component.ts

```
app
   |something1
             |something2
                        -(service.ts)
                        -(service.html)
                          -service.component.ts
```

for more

```
src
  |app
      |folder1
              (.ts file)
      |folder2
              (.ts file1)
              (.ts file2)
  |app.module.ts
```

If I'm importing folder1 .ts file in folder2 .ts file

`import {filecomponent} from 'app/folder1/file.component'`

Importing folder2 file1.ts file in folder2 file2.ts file

`import {file1component} from './file1.component'`

Importing folder1 .ts file in app.module.ts

`import {filecomponent} from './folder1/file.component'`